# Knex error: "Error [KnexTimeoutError]: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?"

Tags: javascript, postgresql, next.js, knex.js

I'm working on a project for several months. Today I started getting this error: "Error [KnexTimeoutError]: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?".

I've seen other posts here on stackoverflow, that this was an issue with NODE14 and knex <8.0.3. I'm not using these versions, so I don't understand where this error comes from? Here some relevant info:

- "next": "^10.2.3"
- "pg": "^8.6.0"
- knex": "^0.95.6"

The database is on heroku. I've checked the connections - there are connections available.

Here some relevant code:
**knexfile.js**

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      // filename: './dev.sqlite3' 
      database: process.env.DATABASE,
      user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
      password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
      host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
      port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
    }
  }, 
 
  production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: process.env.DATABASE,
      user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
      password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
      host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
      port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
    },
    pool: {
      min: 0,
      max: 50
    },
  }
};
```

Can someone help me with this issue? The error comes and goes and I don't know how to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: "I've checked the connections - there are connections available"  What did you do, and what did you see?

Comment: I've used the Heroku CLI to login and run the command: `heroku pg:info`. There I see f.ex. connections: 10/20 and connection pooling: available. Do you have maybe other suggestions?

Comment: There are literally thousands ways to get that error by messing up something when writing queries in knex. You need to start debugging and trying to figure out what places in your code are actually leaking connections and fix the application code. You could even reduce max connections to something like 2-5 while debugging this.